# In my case, how to pass data from child component to parent component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, rxjs, react-router

**Here is the parent component's part**

```js
render() {

    return (
      <>
        <Container fluid>
          <Row>
            <Col lg="3">
              <Profile

                edit={() => this.toggleModal(1)}
                loading={this.state.loading}
                title="Your Profile"
                image={this.context.userData.profilepic}
                firstname={this.state.data.firstname}
                lastname={this.state.data.lastname}
                highschool={this.state.data.user_high_schools}
                desc={this.state.data.dob}


              />
            </Col>
```

**here is the child component**

```js
return (
    <>
      <Row>
        <Col lg='4'>
          <InputGroup className='mt-1'>
            { university.id > 0 ?
                <Input id={university.id} bsSize='sm' placeholder="University name" value={university.system_university.name} onChange={props.handleUniversityChange} /> :
                <Input id={university.id} name='universityid' type='select' bsSize='sm' placeholder="Apply date" value={university.universityid} onChange={props.handleUniversityChange} >
```

**So, my problem is on the child component**, there's value name `{university.system_university.name}` and it contains the value that I wanted. But I really don't know or doubtful to pass this value from child component to the parent component.
I hope you guys understood my question,

Thanks.

Comment: As you tagged your question `react-redux` use redux to update from your child level

Comment: just how? can you explain me more?

Answer (score 0):

so what do you want to do?

react is single source of truth, you should pass a callback function into child from parent

for example:

Parent component

```
const handleUniversityChange = (data) => {
  /* do some staff with your data from within child component */
}

return (
  <Child onUniversityChange={handleUniversityChange} />
)
```

Child component

```
const handleUniversityChange = e => {
  props.onUniversityChange(e.target.value)
}

return (
  <input onChange={handleUniversityChange} />
)
```